# Wait until redirect has been successful

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have an html page and it redirects or stays on the page if a given condition is met. In this instance though, the page loads, and then redirects to the next one which is rather annoying to see as a user so I was wondering if there is a way in javascript to make sure that the redirect(if the condition is met) is successful before anything is shown to the user? I appreciate all you help beforehand and thank you for taking some of your time to help me.

Comment: If you load another page, the old one can't run JS.

Comment: [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all elements hidden through css by default and then show them if the logic makes you stay on the page

Wrap everything in a parent that is display:none by default

```
<div id='wrapper' style='display:none'>

</div>


if(doNotRedirect === true){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: How would I control the css if the condition being met is whether or not a javascript variable is true or false? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have added a sample

Comment: Ok thankyou. Also how do I add a fade-in in this example because it is rather abrupt to load everything at once. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can doit easily if you can add Jquery. It has a fadeIn method that let's you do something like $("#wrapper").fadeIn();